# With Ipc Main and Ipc Render how do you send a whole form?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, ipc

I understand that to send information you do

```
let {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");

ipcRenderer.send("the-form", "the information");
```

and then receive it by

```
ipcMain.on('the-form', function(event, theData) {
    console.log(theData);
});
```

However I'm not sure how to send an entire form and grab the data inside the form.

```
Resolved
```

edit: I gave the form an ID and then used

```
$("#formName").serialize();
```

which returned a string of the form data.

But you can use

```
$("#formName").serializeArray()
```

Which will return an Array of the form data.

Comment: Are you going to send the form data form the rederer to main process?

Comment: By your code, you are sending the string "the information" through the "the-from" channel

Comment: Let me know what are you going to do exactly

Comment: Send the form as stringified json data and then parse again afterwards

Comment: i will try that kevin